# Can't create an instance using FactoryGirl and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using FactoryGirl4.8.0, RSpec3.5.0, Rails5.0.2, and Ruby2.4.1.

I wrote my spec like this:

foo_languages_translators.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo_languages_translator, class: 'Foo::LanguagesTranslator' do
    translator nil
    language nil
  end
end
```

foo_languages_translator_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe JobOfferTranslationLanguagable, type: :model do
  describe '#hoge' do
     let!(:foo_languages_translator) do
       create(
         :foo_languages_translator,
         translator_id: 1,
         foo_language_id: 1
       )
     end
     ... ...
   end
end
```

then I got error:

```
NameError:
       uninitialized constant Foo::LanguagesTranslator::FooLanguage
```

in

```
create(
         :foo_languages_translator,
```

section.

I've tried many things to do solve it, but I have no idea what is wrong.
I'd appreciate it if you have any hints to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let!(:foo_languages_translator) do
  FactoryGirl.create(
    :foo_languages_translator,
    translator_id: 1,
    foo_language_id: 1
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Instead of

```
let!(:foo_languages_translator) do
  create(
    :foo_languages_translator,
    translator_id: 1,
    foo_language_id: 1
  )
end
```

Try creating an object with following attributes

```
let!(:foo_languages_translator) do
  create(
    :foo_languages_translator,
    translator_id: 1,
    language_id: 1
  )
end
```

Please, not down I had used `language_id` instead of `foo_languag_id`.
In your factory, you have used association `language` instead of `foo_language`.

Please let me know if it didn't solve your issue